# How can I disable my iPad's screen turning on when there is a notification?

Tags: ipad, notifications

I have an iPad mini 2. Also I'm using Telegram application. When someone sends me a new message into telegram, my iPad's screen will be turned on *(light on)*.. and that's a huge problem for me .. Because I'm a member of lots of groups and channels  so I have more than 1000 new messages per day. And honestly I'm worried about my iPad's screen, I concern it will be broken, because it will be turn on/off constantly.

Anyway is there any approach to I disable the relationship between "my iPad's screen" and "new notifications"?

Answer (score 2):

I think, you have two (or maybe three) possibilities:

**1. The "Do not disturb"-mode**

When the "Do not disturb"-mode is enabled, your iPad won't make any sound and does not turn on the screen, when you get a notification. But you can still see the notifications on your lockscreen, when you turn on the display manually.

[image: do not disturb]

**2. Turn of notifications for Telegram**

If you turn of the notifications for Telegram, you won't be notified about any message. That would solve your problem, but I think you still want to see notifications for some of your chats?

**(3. Mute some chats)**

Since I'm not using Telegram, I'm not sure, if this is possible. But any modern messenger has options to mute individual chats for a while, so they won't send you push-notifications anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this and there is now another way to receive notifications without having the screen light up.

Swipe right on a notification and click on manage. Then click deliver quietly. Notifications will not alert you but are sent directly to the notification centre.